# Python: get number of occurrences based on condition

Tags: python

If I have list of integers and a function `getErrorType(int)` that returns some enum type, what's a Pythonic way to get a dictionary where the key is the enum type and value is the count of how many values in the array returned that error type?

Example:
`arr = [1, 2, 3]
getErrorType(1) returns EXCEPTION
getErrorType(2) returns MALFORMED_DATA
getErrorType(3) returns EXCEPTION`

I want to be able to get: `{EXCEPTION: 2, MALFORMED_DATA: 1}`

Answer (score 0):

I would use dict comprehension

```
d={getErrorType(a):a for a in arr}
```

EDIT:

ok to get the counts like OP said, i would do something like this

```
d={x: [getErrorType(a) for a in arr].count(x) for x in set([getErrorType(a) for a in arr])}
```

Though this may make it too hard to read to be pythonic/////

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirement _value is the count of how many values in the array returned that error type_.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ok should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}

for a in arr:
    error_type = getErrorType(a)
    if error_type in data:
        data[error_type] += 1
    else:
        data[error_type] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is an efficient method to keep count using dict comprehension.

I would probably just use an iterative approach using a normal dictionary or a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for num in arr: d[getErrorType(num)] += 1
```

Comment: `defaultdict` a what now?

Comment: It's part of the collections module, and is a subclass of dict. Not really that much of a difference, but you can avoid needing to check for existing key when you are trying to keep count.

Answer (score 0):

Made a generic function just to simulate you could pass the whole `arr` into your function then you could use `.count` on the new list that has the results to form a dicitonary

```
def getErrorType(a):
    return ['Ex' if i % 2 else 'Mal' for i in a ]

arr = [1, 2, 3]
lista = getErrorType(arr)
dicta = {i: lista.count(i) for i in lista}
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 helping.py 
> {'Ex': 2, 'Mal': 1}
> ```

I do not agree with looping through `+= 1` every item to create a dictionary that doesn't seem efficient, I stand by this

Answer (score 0):

Combined some solution above

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for num in set(arr):
    d[getErrorType(num)] += arr.count(num)
```